# php, any way to get the result from split bash command

Tags: php, bash

I need to get the result from split bash command to build a exec file in php.

Example:

my file: `1`

my bash command:

```
split 1 -l 10 test -a 4
```

right now i get more examples file like:

testaaaa, testaaab, testaaac,

I need the result because with that result i need to build a file to look like that:

```
php file.php testaaaa ;
php file.php testaaab ;
php file.php testaaac ;
...
```

any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
echo "[+] Start spliting...\n";

exec("split 1 -l 800 split -a 4");
exec("ls | grep split", $op);

exec("rm -rf mass");

$file = fopen('mass', 'a');

foreach(array_values($op) as $line) {
        fwrite($file, 'php crawler ' . $line . ' ; ' . PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the prefix of the split filenames will be (in `$prefix`), you can get a list of them all using:

```
# 4 = suffix length, change this if you change -a argument to split
$pattern = $prefix . str_repeat("?", 4); 
$files = glob($pattern);
```

`$files` will be set to an array containing all the matching filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I think the php's `exec` function can do the trick :

```
$output = exec('split 1 -l 10 test -a 4');   
// then do whatever you like with the result of the command presented in $output
```

Comment: Have you tried to redirect the output of the command to a file then reading the content of that file with `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: You could add it as an answer and make it as the solution, that would be better, but thanks for the answer this could help some developers in the future ;)

Comment: well I "answered" to my question and it leet me to accept as answer in 9h... so.. I hope i will remind.